# MariaDB Galera does not bootstrap the first node

Tags: mariadb, ubuntu-16.04, galera

I have installed ubuntu 16.04 on a VMware VM. Then I added the repo from mariadb website and I installed the latest version of mariadb 10.1.

The installation works fine

I have then created a file

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/conf.d/cluster.cnf
```

with the following

```
[mysqld]

# Cluster node configurations
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://20.0.1.51"
wsrep_node_address="20.0.1.51"
innodb_buffer_pool_size=800M

# Mandatory settings to enable Galera
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_doublewrite=1
query_cache_size=0
bind-address=0.0.0.0

# Galera synchronisation configuration
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
```

I want only to bootstrap the first node and then add new nodes

So I run

```
sudo service mysql bootstrap
```

But I get this error

```
Jul 03 02:38:07 db1 mysqld[14779]:          at gcomm/src/pc.cpp:connect():162
Jul 03 02:38:07 db1 mysqld[14779]: 2016-07-03  2:38:07 140418873596160 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs_core.cpp:gcs_core_open():208: Failed to open backend connection: -110 (Connection timed ou
Jul 03 02:38:07 db1 mysqld[14779]: 2016-07-03  2:38:07 140418873596160 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs.cpp:gcs_open():1379: Failed to open channel 'my_wsrep_cluster' at 'gcomm://20.0.1.51': -11
Jul 03 02:38:07 db1 mysqld[14779]: 2016-07-03  2:38:07 140418873596160 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs connect failed: Connection timed out
Jul 03 02:38:07 db1 mysqld[14779]: 2016-07-03  2:38:07 140418873596160 [ERROR] WSREP: wsrep::connect(gcomm://20.0.1.51) failed: 7
Jul 03 02:38:07 db1 mysqld[14779]: 2016-07-03  2:38:07 140418873596160 [ERROR] Aborting
Jul 03 02:38:08 db1 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 03 02:38:08 db1 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Jul 03 02:38:08 db1 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 03 02:38:08 db1 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Its the systemd thing. On systems that has systemd, one should use **galera_new_cluster** to bootstrap a new cluster.
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/systemd/